# To include a block of code in chef recipe to skip the already unzipped directory and its files contents

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to add a block of code inside a chef recipe to skip the directory that is already has unzipped files and not to update the contents.

What i have done so far.

1. Unzipped the file into a location (/opt/oracle/) using chef recipe

What needs to be done:

1. When re-run the chef recipe it should skip the files and directories that are previously unzipped (i.e., to skip /opt/oracle/database and its contents)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If resource you are using is idempotent it will skip doing whatever existing unless you changed something in it. For any other resource you have to write guard clause like only_if or not_if something like that so it skips something you don't want to execute again.

Directory resource is idempotent but how you unzip file using chef recipe is what that will matter. If you are using execute resource you have to guard it to skip if file unzipped already exists since it's not idempotent

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.